# Sign in with Apple ID says invalid responseType

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, apple-sign-in

I need to implement sign in with Apple feature in Android applications, so I followed [instructions of the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplejs/incorporating_sign_in_with_apple_into_other_platforms).

Here is my parameters: `response_type=id_token&client_id=[CLIENT_ID]&redirect_uri=[REDIRECT_URI]&scope=email%20name&response_mode=form_post`

But the OAuth page says 'invalid_request' with description: 'Invalid responseType'.

They said if the `response_type` can be `id_token` and in that case, `response_mode` should be `form_post` so I followed them. But I can't figure out why I can't access the OAuth page.

This is the uri I used to access OAuth page: https://appleid.apple.com/auth/authorize?response_type=id_token&client_id=[CLIENT_ID]&redirect_uri=[REDIRECT_URI]&scope=email%20name&state=[STATE]&response_mode=form_post

When `response_type` is `code`, I can access OAuth page and login successfully.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I changed `response_type` value `id_token` to `code id_token` and the problem solved.

Comment: I want to know how to get clientId and Redirect ID

Comment: I struggled with this, but I saw that the documentation says:

response_type:
Required. The type of response requested. Valid values are code and id_token. You can request only code, or both code and id_token. Requesting only id_token is unsupported. When requesting id_token, response_mode must be either fragment or form_post.